# Receive Wordpress Contactform7 inquiries on multiple email addresses, based upon the department user choses

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Wordpress plugin Contactform7 for customer inquiries. I have a dropdown where customer chooses which dept. they are contacting. Now I want to send these inquiries to related dept that they choose.

E.g. If customer chooses, sales dept. in contact form dropdown, Then only sales@....com should receive the email and not marketing, accounts or other departments.

Comment: you can use contact form 7 pipes check this for more details http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Comment: Can you please refer this link https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-send-email-based-on-dropdown-value-selected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try This...

```
[select your-recipient "Sales|sales@mydomain.com"
                    "Marketing|maketing@mydomain.com"
                    "Accounts|accounts@mydomain.com"]
```

Comment: Thanks shravan, that really helps!

Comment: I wish I could, it was a comment by you not an answer. What to do?

Comment: Also my reputation is not 15 yet, so I can't see the option to mark accepted, Sorry! But that was helpful. Thanks!